# Difference between evictAll and refresh

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

What is the difference between evictAll and refresh :

```
em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict(AdminUtilisateur.class, user);
```

and

```
em.refresh(em.getReference(AdminUtilisateur.class, user.getId()));
```

And when should i use each one?

Thank you.

Comment: find the anwser here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137057/hibernate-refresh-evict-replicate-and-flush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**evict** : Mark an instance as no longer needed in the cache.

**refresh** : Refresh the state of the instance from the database, overwriting changes made to the entity

Comment: you can explain more than that @vvs